# Удаление папок cache

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь удалить папки через root права, по одной папки удаляет без проблем, но когда, я делаю в массив ссылки на папки, то программа зависает, можно как нибудь проверить удалять через Asynctask ?

```
String app[] = {"/data/data/com.android.chrome/cache", "/data/data/com.android.camera/cache",
                     "/data/data/com.android.email/cache", "/data/data/com.android.gallery/cache",};


            for(int i = 0; i < app.length; i++){


                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), app[i]);
                new DirectoryCleaner(dir).clean();
                dir.delete();

            }


            public class DirectoryCleaner {
                private final File mFile;

                public DirectoryCleaner(File file) {
                    mFile = file;
                }

                public void clean() {
                    if (null == mFile || !mFile.exists() || !mFile.isDirectory()) return;
                    for (File file : mFile.listFiles()) {
                        delete(file);
                    }
                }

                private void delete(File file) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
                            delete(child);
                        }
                    }
                    file.delete();

                }
            }
```

Comment: А при чём тут `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, если Вы удаляете папки в памяти приложений.

Comment: а что нужно убрать этот метод?

Comment: У Вас в массиве абсолютные пути и добавлять к ним ничего не нужно `File dir = new File(app[i]);`

Comment: да , я же это понял, но теперь , не могу понять, как можно сделать ,чтоб программа не зависала при удалении